# "What is funny in people being injured?" vs "What is funny in peoples' being injured?"

Tags: gerunds, possessives, grammaticality-in-context, idiomatic-language

Consider this as a question you asked from someone who thinks prank videos (stupid ones) are funny, especially those that show people getting hit severely or fall.

Which one of the following fits to the context?

> 1. What is funny in people being injured?
> 2. What is funny in people's being injured?

I guess both are grammatical and valid, but they convey different things.

First sentences asks about funny things about the injured people while I want to disparage their interest in such videos.

Considering the context, I think the second one should be used because that possessive apostrophe makes it clear what we are deprecating- laughing at the kind of hardship that people are facing in the video.

---

So, do you agree with me on this? Can I use the second sentence? Would you please tell me your opinions?

Comment: I'd say "what's so funny about people being injured?"

Answer (score 4):

Neither. You should say "What is funny **about** people being injured / getting hurt?" where the second option is a more casual idiom. "People" in both cases is a general noun, not referring to one or more specific person(s), so you don't need to pluralize it as "peoples"; we usually reserve "peoples" for multiple distinct groupings such as "the many indigenous peoples of Africa".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61003/discussion-on-answer-by-rhythmatic-what-is-funny-in-people-being-injured-vs).