# A new look on the "possessive+ gerund" vs "objective pronoun + gerund"

Tags: gerunds, possessives

Today I asked a question on this issue and my intention was to know more about the difference between the two sentences that I provided in the question, but [it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133445/what-is-funny-in-people-being-injured-vs-what-is-funny-in-peoples-being-inj/133455?noredirect=1#comment269538_133455) was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37280/which-is-the-correct-gerund-clause-peoples-killing-animals-or-people-killi#) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund).

Although I didn't ask whether those examples are grammatically correct, I accept that it's a potential duplicate since my examples were not chosen carefully.

Let's get back to my problem with such sentences. Suppose that you want to say something in a comment (like facebook) and there is not enough context to rule out some options. Consider the following examples:

> 1. He liked the manager signing the paper.
> 2. He liked the manager's signing the paper.

In nutshell, I think

- First sentence means he liked that specific manager who was signing the paper.
- Second one means he liked the way that manger signed the paper.

Would you please tell me your opinion on this?

Comment: _"He liked the manager's signing **of** the paper"_ is the interpretation invited by the second, as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect example. In this case, the two **do** mean something different, exactly as you suspected. You could also say "He liked **that** the manager **was** signing the paper." to avoid the gerund and retain the meaning of the second definition/example.

Comment: Your example is ungrammatical in BrE since "like" doesn't license a content clause on its own. It's fine with "it", though: "He liked **it** that the manager was signing the paper".